# Rank of free groups

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

In Johnson's 'Topics in the Theory of Group Presentations', one can find this theorem after the definition of free groups using the universal property.

Theorem. Free groups of different ranks are not isomorphic.

Proof. Let $F$ be free on a subset $X$ with $|X|= \omega$, and let $G$ be any group. Then it is the burden of definition of free group by the universal property that the mappings $X \to G$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the homomorphisms $F \to G$. Thus, there are exactly $2^{\omega}$ homomorphisms from $F$ to $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Since this number is invariant under isomorphism, we see that $2^{\omega}$, and hence the rank $\omega$, is determined by the isomorphism class of $F$.

Isn't the author assuming that $2^{|X|}=2^{|Y|} \Rightarrow |X| = |Y|$?

I have seen this post over here, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67473/equality-of-cardinality-of-power-set, which says that this statement is independent from ZFC. So is the proof wrong?

Comment: In a course I took I was given an almost equivalent proof but I am confident it only was claimed for enumerable or finitely gerenerated groups. Maybe it's only true for those?

Comment: Johnson doesn't say anything abou this matter. He doesnt specify these ranks to be enumerable or finite.

Comment: It would not be the first time when a proof in a textbook was wrong. As for your question, the answer is self-evident.

Comment: Well, maybe I was forgetting something. I just wanted to be sure.

Comment: But the theorem is still correct because, for an infinite set $X$, the cardfinality of the free group on $X$ is the same as $X$ irself.

Answer (score 1):

Let me prove this in a different way. Observe that a free group $F(X)$ on a set $X$ is a free product (coproduct in the category of groups) of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ indexed over $X$. Now, there is an adjunction $(-)^{ab} \dashv i$ where $(-)^{ab}$ is the abelianization functor from the category **Grp** of groups into the subcategory **Ab** of abelian groups and $i : \textbf{Ab} \hookrightarrow \textbf{Grp}$ is the inclusion functor. Since $(-)^{ab}$ is a left adjoint, hence it preserves colimits and in particular, coproducts. Thus, $F(X)^{ab}$ is a coproduct indexed over $X$ in the category of abelian groups, that is, a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}^{ab} = \mathbb{Z}$ indexed over $X$ (in other words, a free abelian group/free $\mathbb{Z}$-module with basis $X$).

Now, assume that there is an isomorphism $F(X) \xrightarrow{\cong} F(Y)$ for sets $X$ and $Y$. Since a functor preserves isomorphisms, hence applying the abelianization functor $(-)^{ab}$ to the isomorphism and using the above argument shows that

$\oplus_X \mathbb{Z} \cong \oplus_Y \mathbb{Z}$

Now, $\mathbb{Z}$, being a commutative ring, implies that it has the invariant basis number property. In other words, any two bases of a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module have the same cardinality. Thus, $|X| = |Y|$.

Comment: You can do the last part without invoking the harder IBN property by moding out by the multiples of $2$, which yields vector spaces over $F_2$, and invoke that two bases of a vector space have the same cardinality, a more elementary than IBN for commutative rings.

Comment: Yes that's right. But then again, the proof of IBN for a general commutative ring also involves moding out by any maximal ideal and turn the free modules into vector spaces over the corresponding field. So quite the same idea.